# (Approximately) bijective proof of $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$?

Tags: geometry-of-numbers, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Given $A,B\in {\Bbb Z}^2$, write $A \leftrightarrows B$ if the
interior of the line segment $AB$ misses
${\Bbb Z}^2$.

For $r>0$, define
$S_r:=\{ \{A, B\} \mid  A,B\in {\Bbb Z}^2,\|A\|<r,\|B\|<r, \left| \|A\|-\|B\| \right|<1 \text{ and } A \leftrightarrows B \}\ .$

A little calculus gives the equivalence of $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ and
$$\lim_{r\to\infty} \frac{|S_r|}{(2r)^3} = 1\ .$$

Of course $(2r)^3$ counts lattice points in a cube $C_r:=[-r,r)^3$.

Question: Does there exist an approximately bijective proof of this
limit (or some variant), one that matches most of $S_r$ with most of $C_r$?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there should be?

Comment: @Greg Martin  1) There do exist reasonably elementary evaluations of $\zeta(2)$ (no Fourier analysis, no contour integration, etc.) so perhaps it's possible to unwind one of them.  2) Any combinatorialist presented with a combinatorial identity naturally wonders whether a bijective proof exists - I don't know of any serious candidates for natural combinatorial facts with no natural proofs. 

 

Comment: Interesting question. Can you spell out the calculus a bit? I see various starts but not a clear path.

Comment: Interesting question, does this generalize to $\zeta(2k)$?

Comment: Roughly (and not rigorously), each pair $A,B$ contains a first point reading clockwise, say $A$. The condition $|\,||A||−||B||\,|<1$ on $B$ in ${\Bbb R^2}$ locates $B$ in a half-annulus of area about $2\pi||A||$. This half-annulus contains a number of lattice points about equal to it's area, and of those, about $1/\zeta(2)$ satisfy $A⇆B$. Now do a double integral for the possible locations of $A$, first by norm, then by angle. The proportion of points where $A⇆B$ may not behave so will in a thin region, but some integration by parts makes everything legal.

Comment: @Greg Martin Why don't you start with more simple question about (the same) density of primitive poits (poits with coprime integer coordinates)?

Comment: Considering that this would essentially provide a geometric interpretation of the Basel problem, the following proof perhaps could be transformed into what you are looking for: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/Cosmic.pdf. I am not really sure though.

Comment: The same question (of the title of original post) is asked and answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9465/is-there-a-finitary-solution-to-the-basel-problem

Answer (score 10):

A proof of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$ is described in a youtube video that I may find and post later today, after it appeared in a paper that I may cite here later today, so I'll let this present posting serve as a reminder to get back to this when I have more time. (As I thought might happen, someone beat me to the URL for the video. See the comment below.) (Another postscript: The paper is by Johan Wästlund. [Here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ewastlund/Cosmic.pdf) is the preprint.)

This involves a one-to-two correspondence (so just construe "bi-" in "bijective" as referring to that "two").

It goes like this. First observe that the proposition to be proved is easily seen to be equivalent to $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{odd } n\,\in\,\mathbb Z} \frac 1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}4 $.

Next, approximate this last sum by the sum of squares of the reciprocals of the distances from $0$ of certain points on the circle of circumference $2^n$ that touches the line $y=0$ in the plane $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ at the point $(0,0)$. Those specified points are the those whose distance measured along the circle from $(0,0)$ is an odd integer.

The central lemma is that if $n$ increases by $1$, then that sum does not change. This reduces the problem to the the case $n=1$, and in that case the sum is $\pi^2/4$.

The proof of the lemma is from secondary-school geometry: Through each of the specified points draw the line through the very top of the circle. That line intersects the next circle, the case $n+1$, at two points. Show that those are two of the points at odd-integer arc lengths from $(0,0)$ and that the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of the distances from those two points to $(0,0)$ is equal to the reciprocal of the square of the distance to $(0,0)$ from the point you started with. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Maybe this is the video? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls

Comment: @thedude That's the one! $\qquad$

Comment: The Wästlund paper [Summing inverse squares by Euclidean geometry](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/Cosmic.pdf) was also [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95711/approximately-bijective-proof-of-zeta2-pi2-6/416799#comment545305_95711) by @Halbort.

Comment: @LSpice : So maybe the moral of your comment is that Halbort should have posted an answer?